# Uploading Custom Posts Types to Wordpress with WP All Import

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wpallimport

I'm trying to import an XML file into ACF with the plugin WP All Import, but I ran into some problems.

I have a custom post type called `loja` and the posts of type `loja` have a Relational Taxonomy Field that is a multi select:

[image]

In the XML this field is only a node, and each option of the select is separated by `;` like this:

[image]

I'm importing this specific field with the ACF Add On, this way:

[image]

Unfortunately this is not working very well, because the plugin is importing all the options separated by `;` as one single option:

[image]

How do I import the separate options?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want each item that are separated by semicolons in the Classificacoes node to be a term in the custom taxonomy called "Relational".

If this is correct, you should be able to import this field under the **"Taxonomies, Categories, Tags"** section of the import.

You should see the "Relational" taxonomy listed.  Check it off and it should expand and then select "Each Post has multiple Categories".  Then put your `{CLASSIFICACOES[1]}` field in the box and put a semicolon in the "Separated by" box.